# How to set the classes used in Drupal commerce buttons with Bootstrap theme

Tags: 7, theming, bootstrap-theme

I am working on a site with Drupal commerce, I use the Bootstrap theme and a child theme.
I would like the [add-to-cart] button to have the "btn-default" class, instead of “btn-success". Actually, I want to get rid of the "info" and "warning" classes in many cases where I don't need them and replace them by "default" or "primary".

I saw in /sites/all/themes/bootstrap/bootstrap.api.php

```
/**
 * Allows sub-themes to alter the array used for colorizing text.
 * …
 * @see _bootstrap_colorize_text()
 */
 function hook_bootstrap_colorize_text_alter(array &$texts) {
   // This matches the exact string: "My Unique Button Text".
   $texts['matches'][t('My Unique Button Text')] = 'primary';

  // This would also match the string above, however the class returned would
  // also be the one above; "matches" takes precedence over "contains".
  $texts['contains'][t('Unique')] = 'notice';

  // Remove matching for strings that contain "apply":
  unset($texts['contains'][t('Apply')]);

  // Change the class that matches "Rebuild" (originally "warning"):
  $texts['contains'][t('Rebuild')] = 'success';
}
```

So I tried in /sites/all/themes/[my-sub-theme]/template.php

```
function hook_[my-sub-theme]_colorize_text_alter(array &$texts) {
  // Let's try a dummy change for a test
  $texts['contains'][t('Update cart')] = 'success';
}
```

But I can't see anything changed.

I also saw that /sites/all/themes/bootstrap/includes/common.inc sets a number of values based on the contained string, in which I find th “Update” I am looking for.  the function is
`function _bootstrap_colorize_text($string, $default = '') {…}`
it ends with

```
// Allow sub-themes to alter this array of patterns.
    drupal_alter('bootstrap_colorize_text', $texts);
```

But I still haven't found how to do what I want in my sub theme. and what I read in /sites/all/themes/bootstrap/templates/system/buttons.vars.php won't help me.

Can somebody please explain where to start?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same type of issue (which I will post elsewhere). I'm not sure I have the best answer, but from what I read in the Bootstrap API documentation, I believe your code should read as follows.

```
function [my-sub-theme]_colorize_text_alter(array &$texts) {
  // Let's try a dummy change for a test
  $texts['contains'][t('Update cart')] = 'success';
}
```

The preceding "hook" needs to be entirely replaced by your [my-sub-theme] name.
From what I read, that should be what is needed for this to work. However, I'm having trouble getting it to work myself.